# How YARN does check health of hadoop nodes in YARN web console

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I would like to know how YARN Web UI running at port 8088 consolidates the Datanodes,Namenodes and other cluster components health status.

For example, this is what i see when i open the Web UI.

> Hi guy, your all datanodes are healthy.

Comment: If my answer helps you please consider accepting it.

Comment: Your answer has nothing in common with my question./

Comment: This is very surprising to me you asked how YARN Web UI collects the metrics from the cluster ryt?

Comment: I think you have to rephrase your question and provide what exactly you need.

Comment: I think that YARN doesn't display health of datanodes, only some state, these details are available in NameNode WEB ui interface (it is possible due to heartbeat sent from DataNode to NameNode)

Comment: In YARN the Resource Manager is the master process which gets the heartbeat information from the Node Managers. Therefore YARN has all the metrics related to the cluster. i.e slave health status , containers information through Application Master etc.

Comment: Therefore, your YARN Web UI has to collect the metrics from the Resource Manager using the REST interface.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-ui/src/main/webapp/app/adapters

Answer (score 0):

The **ResourceManager REST API's** allow the user to get information about the cluster - status on the cluster, metrics on the cluster, scheduler information, information about nodes in the cluster, and information about applications on the cluster.

The below example is taken from the official documentation.

Request:

```
GET http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/info
```

Response:

```
{
  "nodes":
  {
    "node":
    [
      {
        "rack":"\/default-rack",
        "state":"NEW",
        "id":"h2:1235",
        "nodeHostName":"h2",
        "nodeHTTPAddress":"h2:2",
        "healthStatus":"Healthy",
        "lastHealthUpdate":1324056895432,
        "healthReport":"Healthy",
        "numContainers":0,
        "usedMemoryMB":0,
        "availMemoryMB":8192,
        "usedVirtualCores":0,
        "availableVirtualCores":8
      },
      {
        "rack":"\/default-rack",
        "state":"NEW",
        "id":"h1:1234",
        "nodeHostName":"h1",
        "nodeHTTPAddress":"h1:2",
        "healthStatus":"Healthy",
        "lastHealthUpdate":1324056895092,
        "healthReport":"Healthy",
        "numContainers":0,
        "usedMemoryMB":0,
        "availMemoryMB":8192,
        "usedVirtualCores":0,
        "availableVirtualCores":8
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

More information can be found from the below link

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

I hope this helps.